# Devise find by username or email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

after setup devise 
i would like to get the user by username or email with in a api session

I passed login to parameters but rails spits out a error

```
User.find_for_database_authentication(:login => params[:username][:email])
```

the overwrite of find_for_database_authentication on model is already done.

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
```

Someone has any hint to spare?

**Devise**

```
class Api::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  respond_to :json

  def create
    resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(:login => params[:username][:email])



    if resource.valid_password?(params[:login][:password])
      sign_in(:user, resource)

      render :json=> {:auth_token=>resource.authentication_token, :email=>resource.email}, :status => :ok
      return
    end
    invalid_login_attempt
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Completed 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Can you show your code for `find_for_database_authentication` ?

Comment: Sure, the questions is now with the code

Comment: Are your login credentials correct, can you do a `puts` and see if the `create` method is getting correct data

Comment: is showing

{"status":422,"error":"Unprocessable Entity"

Comment: that means your data is malformed, you need to fix the data being sent to the controller

Comment: Can you please show us the actual implementation of your `find_for_database_authentication`, not just the name of the method?

Comment: check allowed parameters for this request. add username, email to permitted params.

Comment: Is `params[:username][:email]` correctly spelled?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this: `User.find_by(username: 'username')` or `User.find_by(email: 'your@email.com')`

Answer (score 2):

I did this by overriding `find_for_database_authentication` like this:

```
class User
  def self.find_for_database_authentication(auth_hash)
    self.where("username = :query OR email = :query", query: auth_hash[:email].downcase).first
  end
end
```

Nothing more was needed.

Comment: This is very helpful. But please downcase email in the query `auth_hash[:email].downcase`.